# Error installing PHP 5.3 using phpfarm on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: php

I tried installing php 5.3 using phpfarm and phpenv but I keep getting the following error at make.

```
/tmp/php-build/source/5.3.29/ext/phar/util.c:2142: undefined reference to `BIO_free'
/tmp/php-build/source/5.3.29/ext/phar/util.c:2151: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_create'
/tmp/php-build/source/5.3.29/ext/phar/util.c:2153: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_size'
/tmp/php-build/source/5.3.29/ext/phar/util.c:2156: undefined reference to `EVP_sha1'
/tmp/php-build/source/5.3.29/ext/phar/util.c:2156: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
/tmp/php-build/source/5.3.29/ext/phar/util.c:2165: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
/tmp/php-build/source/5.3.29/ext/phar/util.c:2174: undefined reference to `EVP_SignFinal'
/tmp/php-build/source/5.3.29/ext/phar/util.c:2183: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_destroy'




collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/fpm/php-fpm] Error 1
```

Comment: php 5 is a moderately large compile with tons of options. It would help if we knew what options you enabled and the information above the error you posted. The error you posted is just an exit status ( 1 ) meaning if failed, the lines above will explain WHY it failed.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I have added the error lines above the exit status as suggested.

Comment: You will need o post ALL the errors with php (upsream) or the mailing list - https://secure.php.net/support.php

Comment: @bodhi.zazen PHP 5.3 is not supported version of PHP for a very long time, so you won't find help in the PHP mailing list: https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Well then the OP is likely out of luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting a problem with too new OpenSSL library.  You might try downloading and compiling OpenSSL 0.9.8zg https://openssl.org/source/ and using that version.  But I would rather recommend that if you absolutely have to use PHP 5.3, use a Debian LTS (squeeze) or Ubuntu Precise versions as they have security updates beyond upstream versions provided by Debian and Ubuntu security teams.